# Dynamic textfield not getting cached in TableView didSelectRowAt method

Tags: ios, swift

Actually, I am implementing a dynamic Question-Answer form in which table cells which load with dynamic fields (like., Drop Down, TextField, GridView, etc.,) For this in the cell I created one label for Question and one blank view to render dynamic content of Answer field. If I clicked on the label or on the cell I am able to reach to didSelectRowAt TableView method but if I clicked on dynamic content (like., Inside textField or on the button) not able to reach on didSelectRowAt. Not getting how to tackle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting userInteractionEnabled = NO
This will avoid all the touch events for that particular control. and the events will be handled by the next responder in chain.

Comment: Actually, I want to make it enable to capture the input but the thing is with that also want to get which cell is selected at the current moment so I can assign that question id with a particular answer

Comment: then you will have to manually call didSelectRowAtIndexPath for the particular Cell. where you are receiving touch event for the control.

Comment: Actually, I can do this but as I said my cell will have dynamic content which can be button or textfield or grid So if I followed this approach I have to call it for every different dynamic element of cell

Comment: Sure ya, when I am making User interaction disable for the particular element it is passing control to the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath. I can do this with the case of the label but when it comes to Textfield or button I need to enable User Interaction to capture the action that time I think I need to manually call didSelectRowAtIndexPath or using delegate I have to achieve it

Comment: yeah, that the only solution we have